# Can anyone explain the concept of Action and ActionForm?

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to Struts2.On doing sample programs.I came to know that we are creating a class and extending **Action** and another one class extending **Actionform**.I dont know why we are doing that ?And I can understand that struts contains set of  **custom tag libs** which can be used .We are defining the Action tag and the appropriate form-bean.I could not find the concept and advantage behind this framework. Could anyone provide the links or books where i can find the struts concept.
thanks in advance

Comment: You're conflating Struts 1 terminology with Struts 2 tag. There is no Action or ActionForm in Struts 2. What version are you actually asking about?

Comment: @DaveNewton, We have Action interface in Struts2 We can implement an action using Action interface and in Struts1.3 Action is a class. So this is one advantage of Struts2.

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV `Action` is an interface that isn't required for anything and is more for backwards compatibility than anything else.

Comment: @Govind Rajan: if you are referring sample application from some online resource better post the link so that some one can have a look in it to see what exactly is going there.

Comment: (Mohana is correct, there *is* an `Action` interface, but you'll essentially never use it directly, rather extend `ActionSupport` or use annotations.)

Comment: @umesh I was looking at this link for sample [link]http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts2/Struts2SimpleLogin.html)

Comment: But I got confused the version 1 with struts2.Now got a better idea about it ..Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix up Struts 1 and Struts 2 both are having different architectures

Struts 2 = Struts + WebWork.

Struts2 architecture http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/home.html

Struts2 guides http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/guides.html

Comment: Please link to a current version; S2.0.6 is quite old.

Comment: @DaveNewton: i guess that is because of Google, it always give old version on top :)

Answer (score 3):

Struts is an implementation of MVC. The Action class, in combination with the configuration (struts-config.xml normally) is the controller, deciding based on what the user submits what parts of the model (your business logic, should cotain nothing web-specific).

The ActionForm as mentioned about represents the form submitted by the user.

I personally read Struts in Action many years ago, but that only covers Struts 1. The Struts website itself should be helpful http://struts.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

Struts is far in the past for me, but let's see if I can dredge up a memory to explain.

Struts associates an `Action` class with a request URL.  When that request comes in, Struts looks up the `Action` using the request URL and executes it.

The `ActionForm` associates an HTML form with an Action so Struts can marshall HTTP request parameter name/value pairs and bind them to Java objects.  These Java objects are passed to the `Action` so it can do its execution work.

Struts is rather old now; it's been around since 2000.  The `Action` and `ActionForm` concepts have been part of it from release 1.0.  There are lots of books on Amazon and articles on the web.  If you can't find any, or have to ask here to get some, I'd say you're being far too passive and lazy about it. Fire up Google and get to work.

Comment: I hate that I'm reading answers that say it was "rather old" during 2016.... I wish I wasn't using struts

Comment: I wish you weren't either.  Time for an upgrade.  For security's sake, if nothing else.  https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-6117/Apache-Struts.html

Comment: Its definitely in our backlog....somewhere

Comment: I doubt that very much.  Won't happen unless you advocate for it.